# Access denied after copying server to another server - Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, access-denied

We made a copy of the server image and moved it to another server (the server name changed too). I have access to Central administration, i have access to SQL server, but not to the Sharepoint main page. I get there the access denied page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it in 2013. But in previous versions of SharePoint I know you can't just change the machine name on it.

Well you can do it. But it's not as straightforward as just changing the machine name.

Here's a blog I found which lists the steps required http://www.bluesphereinc.com/blog/renaming-a-sharepoint-20102013-server/

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Works perfect. Thx.